# Message contract wrappername and message body name attribute does not work

Tags: c#, wcf

I have couple of classes which define as message contract and properties define as message body. I specified wrappername and name attribute respectively. It works for parent class but does not work for child class.

Classes:

```
[MessageContract(WrapperName = "ticketstatus",IsWrapped = true)]
public class TicketStatusResponse
{        

    [MessageBodyMember(Name="status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Name="errorcode")]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Name="errormessage")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Name="tasks")]
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(WrapperName="task")]
public class Task
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name="taskname")]
    public string TaskName { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Name="complete")]
    public string Complete { get; set; }
}
```

Response info:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
  <ticketstatus xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <errorcode>0</errorcode>
     <errormessage/>
     <status>Pending</status>
     <tasks xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MessageContractExample.Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Task>
           <a:Complete>1</a:Complete>
           <a:TaskName>task1</a:TaskName>
        </a:Task>
        <a:Task>
           <a:Complete>2</a:Complete>
           <a:TaskName>task2</a:TaskName>
        </a:Task>
     </tasks>
     <ticketno>567890</ticketno>
     <waittime>4</waittime>
  </ticketstatus>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My expected xml tag name of "Task" should be as follows because I change name using wrappername and name attribute:

```
        <a:task>
           <a:complete>2</a:complete>
           <a:taskname>task2</a:taskName>
        </a:task>
```

But i am getting

```
       <a:Task>
           <a:Complete>1</a:Complete>
           <a:TaskName>task1</a:TaskName>
        </a:Task>
```

Why wrapper name and name attribute do not work for child node. How can I fix node name?

Any idea or hints?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `IsWrapped = true` as that is the difference between the classes.